# Fisher information for gamma-Poisson distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, fisher-information

I have $Y$ that is a gamma-Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$ and $\kappa$ is the overdispersion. I'm trying to obtain fisher information but i don't know how to solve expected value of trigamma function, $\psi'(\kappa + y_i)$ in the formula below.

The observed information obtained for k is:
$$
-\sum_i \left[\frac{y_i - \mu_i}{(\kappa + \mu_i)^2} - \frac{1}{\mu_i+\kappa}+\frac{1}{\kappa} + \psi'(\kappa + y_i) - \psi'(\kappa)\right]
$$

Thank you for the help.

Comment: The R programming language has a function [`trigamma`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Special.html) which should help.